# Some thoughts about an equivalent definition of center of a group

Tags: group-theory

As fancy as it may seem, the following form of the *center* fits to some variations by analogy:
$$Z(G)=\{g\in G\mid \varphi(g)g^{-1}\in\{e\}, \forall\varphi\in\operatorname{Inn}(G)\} \tag 1$$
For example, we can adapt $(1)$ by replacing "$\operatorname{Inn}$" with "$\operatorname{Aut}$", thus getting the *absolute center*:
$$L(G)=\{g\in G\mid \varphi(g)g^{-1}\in\{e\}, \forall\varphi\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)\} \tag 2$$
Likewise, if we replace in $(2)$ the trivial subgroup with $Z(G)$, we come up to:
$$H(G)=\{g\in G\mid \varphi(g)g^{-1}\in Z(G), \forall\varphi\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)\} \tag 3$$
which yields the quotient $H(G)/Z(G)\cong\operatorname{Inn}(G)\cap Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$: the group of the *autocentral automorphisms* (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3188843/1007416) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4398580/1007416)). The next step along this way could be replacing back in $(3)$ "$\operatorname{Aut}$" with "$\operatorname{Inn}$", ending up with:
\begin{alignat}{1}
K(G) &= \{g\in G\mid \varphi(g)g^{-1}\in Z(G), \forall\varphi\in\operatorname{Inn}(G)\} \\
\tag 4
\end{alignat}
which, if I'm not mistaken, turns out to be isomorphic to $Z(\operatorname{Inn}(G))$.

By similarity with $(1)$ to $(4)$: are there examples of pairs $(G,N)$, with nontrivial $N\operatorname{char}G$, $N\ne Z(G)$, such that
the subgroups:
$$M_A(N)=\{g\in G\mid \varphi(g) g^{-1}\in N, \forall\varphi\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)\}$$
$$\space\space\space\space\space M_I(N)=\{g\in G\mid \varphi(g)g^{-1}\in N, \forall\varphi\in\operatorname{Inn}(G)\}$$
play any role in the knowledge of $G$?

Comment: It's not $Z(\mathrm{Inn}(G))$, but rather the subgroup of $G$ that maps to it under the canonical map. That is known as "the second center" $Z_2(G)$. Iterating gives the well-known "upper central series of $G$".