# Does this series $L_{i+1}(G)=\{g\in G\mid \varphi(g)g^{-1}\in L_i(G), \forall\varphi\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)\}$ have a name?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, definition

From the comment to [this other](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4401563/1007416) question of mine, I have learned that the series ($i=0,1,2,\dots$):
$$Z_{i+1}(G)=\{g\in G\mid \varphi(g)g^{-1}\in Z_i(G), \forall\varphi\in\operatorname{Inn}(G)\} \tag 1$$
where $Z_0(G)=1$ (and hence $Z_1(G)=Z(G)$, the *center* of $G$) is named *the upper central series of $G$*. Does this other series:
$$L_{i+1}(G)=\{g\in G\mid \varphi(g)g^{-1}\in L_i(G), \forall\varphi\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)\} \tag 2$$
where $L_0(G)=1$ (and hence $L_1(G)=L(G)$, the *absolute center* of $G$) have a name?

Comment: This paper studies lower central series of semidirect products:
https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01714012v2/file/lcds_2.pdf but it makes me think that your series might well be an ingredient of the upper central series of something like $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\ltimes G$